# Ajax get hidden form in PHP file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a PHP file that pulls information from a SQL database. I need to refresh this information every few seconds and plot onto a Google map. The map code is contained on another page and is within the header for the location marker etc, is there a way I can pass the PHP data to the map?

Overview:
data.php (contains information from database)
map.php (file that contains map to refresh every 10 seconds)

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: run js on map.php to call data.php ever X seconds

Answer (score 0):

You need to call 2 different XMLHttpRequest every 10 secondes (thanks to [setTimeout method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)) ;

- 1 to recover data.php informations ;
- 1 to send it to map.php.

In your php files, you will have to code the behavior to adopt when getting those requests.